# Rails tabs instead spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabs, spaces

Is there any way to to setup Rails generating files with tabs instead spaces?

Or maybe is there any way to auto replacing spaces to tabs in gedit?

Cause I really prefered tabs and it's really take some time to replace spaces to tabs in new generated files by Rails.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in gedit, try the [Tab Converter](http://www.stambouliote.de/projects/gedit_plugins_old.html) plugin.

(Don't think there's a way to do it directly in Rails.)

Comment: great, exactly what I've needed, but unfortunetly it doesn't work in my gedit...
tryed to disable other plugins, but no good.

but anyway thanks!

Comment: @Sergei, yeah just noticed that page was last updated in 2006. :) Try their mail list or irc channel, I'm sure other users want to convert between spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a simple way. The generators begin copying a template file into your project and then substitute the various variable names into that template.

The template files that are copied into your project use spaces, so you'd need to monkey patch some filter into the generators; a filter that would regex replace the leading spaces with tabs. Not an ideal solution.